# Como fazer pra uma matriz multidimensional ler dados inseridos pelo usuario?

Tags: ruby

```
F1=[['1','2','3'],['4','5','6'],['7','8','9']]
print "\nJogador 1: Escolha uma linha e uma coluna no tabuleiro:\n"
L=gets.chomp
C=gets.chomp
F1[L][C]='X'
```

A ideia aqui é construir um jogo da velha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, testei seu código, faltava apenas um to_i para converter a entrada em inteiro, não sei se essa era sua dificuldade. Fiz algumas modificações em seu código.

```
tabuleiro = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

def show(tabuleiro)
  puts "\nTABULEIRO\n\n"
  tabuleiro.each do |r|
    puts r.each { |p| p }.join(' ')
  end
end

loop do
  puts "\nJogador 1: Escolha uma linha do tabuleiro:"
  linha = gets.chomp.to_i
  puts "\nJogador 1: Escolha uma coluna do tabuleiro:"
  coluna = gets.chomp.to_i
  tabuleiro[linha][coluna] = 'X'

  show(tabuleiro)
end
```

Resultado:

> Jogador 1: Escolha uma linha do tabuleiro: 0
>
> Jogador 1: Escolha uma coluna do tabuleiro: 0
>
> TABULEIRO
>
> X 2 3
>
> 4 X 6
>
> 7 8 X

Comment: Sim era era a dificuldade, acabei achando a solução em um site em inglês, mas obrigado por sua resposta!

Comment: @Wandaymo caso a resposta tenha sido satisfatória, favor aceitar como resposta correta. Obrigado.